# Inconsistent User Profile Navigation on Mobile Meta Site

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, mobile-web

I'm getting a bit of inconsistency between Meta Stackoverflow and Stackoverflow when I'm using the mobile version.

Here's what it looks like on SO.[image: Appearance of mobile site on SO, with a large gap between the top and bottom portions.]

Notice the large gap between the top Stackoverflow header and the first comment in my inbox?  That's actually a very long URL to my profile.

Here's what it looks like on MSO. [image: Appearance of mobile site on MSO, with no gap between the top and bottom portions.]

There's *no gap* between the top and bottom, which means that there isn't a space for me to get into my profile, like there is with SO.

This is a bit inconsistent and it has thrown me off.  I've repro'd the issue using the mobile version on my desktop, as well as my mobile phone.

Comment: Seems like the issue is that all the metas are missing a `<br>` or a `<tr>` between the badges and the rep.

Comment: The first example may be convenient to click, but it *looks* like a layout mistake (like there should be some text to the right of the icon) and IMO should be revised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next build, some styles present in the meta theme weren't applied to the main site...they'll match after the build.